# How to use the function .getLastRow() in google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm pretty new to Google Script and I've been working on a line of code that is bothering me right now. What I'm trying to do is make the computer read through a range of cells in the spread sheet, then print them all out, but stop at the last row. But, as I've tried using the function .getLastRow() in the for loop or just making a variable, it doesn't work.  (There are some parts where the code is redundant and not related to the problem so you can ignore that.)

```
function myFunction()
{

  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1F4zEJXKN3iobK8b89Ub94dd77Tdk70H0X8aFCSCmvRs");
  var activeSheetOne = spreadSheet.getSheetByName("New Family Responses");
  var activeSheetTwo = spreadSheet.getSheetByName("Existing Family Responses");

  var readingGender = activeSheetOne.getRange("E3:E").getValues();
  var lastRow = readingGender.getLastRow();
  var loopVar = 0;

  for (var i=0; i < lastRow; i++) {
    Logger.log(readingGender[loopVar][0]);
    loopVar = loopVar + 1;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getLastRow` is a method  of classes [Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) and [Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range), which simply means that whenever you write `something.getLastRow()`, that `something` must be a sheet or a range. (As Zig Mandel noted, there is an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1349) concerning the functionality of the range method; normally it's used for  a sheet.)

In your code, `activeSheetOne` is a **sheet**, applying `getRange("E3:E")` you get a **range**, and then applying `getValues()` you get just an **array** of values. This means an ordinary [JavaScript array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) with which you work using JavaScript methods  and properties, not Google Apps Script methods.

So, replace the line `var lastRow = readingGender.getLastRow();` by

```
var lastRow = readingGender.length;
```

where [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) is the length of an array.

Also, your code with both `i` and `loopVar`  is a mix of `for` and `while` loops. You don't need both; a `for` loop will do.

```
for (var i=0; i < lastRow; i++) {
  Logger.log(readingGender[i][0]);
}
```

Suggestion: learn the fundamentals of JavaScript, e.g., with [Codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/javascript), before working with Google Apps Script.

Comment: be aware that range.getLastRow() is currently the same as sheet.getLastRow() see https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1349

Comment: Good point; I never used it for a range myself, and was going off the code in the question. Edited.